# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I am writing a java code in Android Studio to POST to my local webapi. Running through emulator.

`public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:9998/api/users";`

But while POST, below error appears. Even though I am able to POST via postman.

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my code :

```
 RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registration2.this);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.ROOT_URL, parameters,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            Log.e("Result of POST :", response.toString());

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("ERRORAS 2 :", error.toString());
                        }
                    });

            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

            //Intent intent = new Intent(Registration2.this,LandingPage.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

,,,

This is my JSONObject :

```
final JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();


    try {
        parameters.put("FirstName", "Vedaanth");
        parameters.put("LastName", "Pradhan");
        parameters.put("PhoneNumber", "9*******1");
        parameters.put("EmailID", "p******@gmail.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: What is the response from the server when you hit it using POSTMAN?

Comment: It returns autoincremental UserID number, in this case it returns 2.

Comment: Yes, try it once.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting a response whose type is number but in your code, you are expecting a  JsonObject which is causing the issue.

Comment: Shall i change public void onResponse(JSONObject response) to public void onResponse(Integer response) {